# MYSQL event running but not working

Tags: php, mysql, events

I have created mysql to delete table rows, which have lower DATETIME value than NOW(), `SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows event and time counter is running but it dont delete rows. Here is the code:

```
CREATE EVENT minute_event
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 minute
    DO 
      DELETE FROM reservations WHERE 'reservation_end' < NOW();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using single quotes instead of backticks. The expression `'reservation_end' < NOW()` should cause a [MySQL Error #1267](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_cant_aggregate_2collations), because `'reservation_end'` is just a string. It should be:

```
DELETE FROM reservations WHERE `reservation_end` < NOW();
```

or unquoted since `reservation_end` doesn't specifically need to be surrounded by backticks.

Comment: @DeividasJuškevičius What is the column type of `reservation_end`?

Comment: can that cause bacause I' using XAMPP?

Comment: @DeividasJuškevičius Does `SELECT NOW();` give you the correct time you expect?

Comment: I've deleted active event and created the new one and now it seems to be working. Thank you for help